# for each loop calls a heavy function. Does the loop call the function before it is complete

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop that calls a function that produces documents, a crap ton of variables and several emails. The loop will go through about 10-20 iterations on average and I am wondering if it calls the functions simultaneously or if it waits until the function is complete before it calls it again.

```
foreach ($campaign as $key=>$val){
    produce_docs($val['id']);
}

function produce_docs(campaign_id){
    //Big function
    //does not return anything
}
```

Comment: It waits all the nested loops to end before doing another iteration

Comment: See edit. No nested loops, but one function call.

Comment: Still the same. It won't iterate until the function hasn't finished. A function is like a shortcut for repeatable instructions, you could replace the function call by its code and it'd.be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will wait until the function is complete before calling it again.